# NodeJS with portable imagemagick

Tags: node.js, image-processing, imagemagick, portability

I'm building a [NodeJS] <--> [AngularJS+more] app which uses NodeWebkit (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) in order to create Desktop Apps (linux, windows, osx).
In a final version, I would like to include the server in the desktop version so as to create a Standalone application. The problem is that I would need to install Imagemagick in the destination machine, as it is a requirement for image treatment (not a big deal, I only resize images and convert them into png).

The question is: Is there any portable version for any OS that I can use por this purpose? Or Is there any nodejs plugin for simple image treatment that is self-installed (just using npm) and doesn't need any other program to be installed?

Thanks in advance.
Let me know if there's any detail that it's not well specified.